# Bitcoin Exchange only sends funds to P2PKH and P2SH addresses, but my address is Bech32. What can I do to get that fund into my account?

Tags: wallet, p2sh, bech32-address, p2pkh, exodus

This is the email that I've received from my exchange:

> There are three bitcoin address formats currently in use:
>
> P2PKH addresses which begin with the number 1.  P2SH addresses
> starting with the number 3. Bech32 addresses are also known as "bc1
> addresses" starting with bc1. Unfortunately we do not support Bech32
> addresses. The  address formats we accept are noted at the top of the
> Wallet Send page.
>
> You will need to convert the address to either option 1 or 2 to be
> able to send the funds to this external wallet.

How do I convert the address? If that is not an option, what else can I do to get the fund into my Bech32 wallet?

Comment: If I may ask, which exchange is this that still does not support sending to bech32 addresses?

Answer (score 3):

> How do I convert the address?

You cannot. The receiver, and the receiver alone, is responsible for deciding which addresses they accept payments to. Trying to convert an address from one type to another is a great way to burn funds.

> If that is not an option, what else can I do to get the fund into my Bech32 wallet?

Request a P2PKH or P2SH address from the receiver wallet software/service. Most will let you choose the address type, but how depends on the specific software or service you're using.

Comment: Thank you for that. For anyone else on Exodus wallet, go to https://www.exodus.com/support/article/1480-bitcoin-faqs-learn-more-about-btc#find-address to find the solution.